# Research on gift structure and satisfaction: one large gift or two small ones?

Tags: social-psychology, economics, behavioral-economics

I'm familiar with some research into  the subject of gift giving, for example Dan Ariely suggests that [giving cash is less effective than buying somebody something](http://danariely.com/2008/07/04/gifts-ridiculous-or-useful/). Other studies show that [money spent on others makes you more happy than money spent on yourself](http://www.people.hbs.edu/mnorton/dunn%20aknin%20norton.pdf).

Does anybody know of a study regarding the problem of whether its best to give one single large gift or split the gift into several smaller ones?

Comment: Just conjecture, but it seems as though smaller gifts are generally acceptable, while larger gifts might be seen as too much.

Comment: I'm more interested  in the easily splitable gifts.
For example is it better to give 2 wine bottles at once or give 1 one bottle wait a week and give the second one.